# Bottom padding div error

Tags: html, css, padding

I have an strange bottom padding in a div, even if I set the `padding` to 0. I think It's something inherited from something, but I removed all the paddings to see what is causing It and It still happens.

This is my CSS:

```
.magazinelistdiv {
width: 804px;
}

.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv {
width: 800px;
border-top: 1px solid #333388;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333388;
padding-bottom: 0px;    
}

.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv div {
display:inline-block;

font-size: 20px;
width: 65px;
text-align: center;
}

.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv .zero{
color: red;
}

.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv .id {
width: 40px;
margin: 7px 0;
}

.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv .number { 
width: 100%; 
}

.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv .text {
font-size: 8px;
width: 100%;
}

.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv .magazine {
width: 410px;
text-align: left;
}

.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv .visits {
font-style: italic;
color: #444;
}

.magazinelistdiv div:hover { 
background-color: #eee; 
}

.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
padding: 3px;
background-color: #ddd;
border-radius: 0.3em;
-moz-border-radius: o.3em;
-webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
border: 1px solid #333;
display:block;
width: 390px;
}
```

And this is my output html:

```
<div class="magazinelistdiv">
    <div class="magrowdiv odd" id="magrowdiv1">
            <div class="id">1</div> 
            <div class="magazine"><a href='index.php?act=magazine&id=5'>Mag1</a></div>
            <div class="issues zero">
                <div class="number">0</div>
                <div class="text">Issues</div>
            </div> 
            <div class="series zero">
                <div class="number">0</div>
                <div class="text">Series</div>
            </div>
            <div class="chapters zero">
                <div class="number">0</div>
                <div class="text">Chapters</div>
            </div> 
            <div class="pages zero">
                <div class="number">0</div>
                <div class="text">Pages</div>
            </div> 
            <div class="visits zero">
                <div class="number">0</div>
                <div class="text">Visits</div>
            </div> 
            <div></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I think I have a lot of errors in the CSS, since more things happens, but I'm not sure how to fix them, but I'm specially focused on that bottom padding thing.

To be more specific, all the divs within the `magrowdiv` div have a bottom padding, and they shouldn't have it.

Comment: have you tried it on a different browser, perhaps multiple browsers maybe?

Comment: You just posted a lot of code along with a general gripe...  what exactly is your specific question?  What `div` are you talking about?  Have you inspected the DOM with the developer tools in Safari, Chrome, Firefox or Explorer?  Voting to close unless more information can be added.

Comment: Add in your question the produced HTML and not HTML with PHP, will help more.

Comment: 1. It would be more helpful if you would paste the output of the file (the html), not the php.
2. " in a div" - please be more specific. Which div?

Comment: I have edited the post. To be more specific, all the divs within the 'magrowdiv' have that bottom padding that I don't know where comes from.

Comment: Yes, I've tried in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, and looks almost the same on all of them.

Comment: Also, put your page through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and fix any errors.

Comment: I did included it in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from what you have posted.  However, if I change the following

```
.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv .id {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 7px 0;
}
```

to

```
.magazinelistdiv .magrowdiv .id {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0; /* REMOVE THE TOP & BOTTOM MARGIN */
}
```

it tightens up the `divs`.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jYn8F/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've posted, you have two superfluous closing div tags in the HTML.